# Invisible Samba Share on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares, samba

I have a linux server running Samba, with 4 shares. I have a laptop running Windows 7.

The laptop can see and use all 4 shares when viewing the server in the Network, and I can map all 4 shares. After the shares are mapped, I can see all 4 of them using *net use* in the command line. However, I can only see three of the shares in Explorer. One share in particular is invisible.

This problem persists regardless of what name the share has in the server config, and all 4 shares are configured the same way. I have already tried to delete and re-add the mapped share through *net use*. There are no drive letter conflicts, and the share remains invisible no matter how many times I map the drive to other drive letters.

The other three shares work perfectly. The invisible share used to be visible.

Why can't I view the share in Explorer?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to map to the same server with more than one username?  Windows doesn't like that for some reason.

Comment: No, the only account on the server is mine, so I'm only using one username.